# Array transformation with angular.forEach - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data I'm fetching from a `REST API` that I want to create a new `object` using `Angular` before passing it back to my `API` using `$http`

```
orderItem:  { 
    id: 159
    name: Empanadas (Choice of 2)
    description: Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella
    price: 700
    available: 1
    created_at: 2016-01-31 16:50:31
    updated_at: 2016-01-31 16:50:31
    menu_category_id: 41
    restaurant_id: 11
    menu_modifier_groups: 
        [  { 
            id: 9
            name: Choose 2 Empanadas
            instruction: null
            min_selection_points: 2
            max_selection_points: 2
            force_selection: 1
            created_at: 2016-02-01 01:03:35
            updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:12:23
            menu_item_id: 159
            restaurant_id: 11
                menu_modifier_items: 
                [  { 
                    id: 34
                    name: Diced Beef
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:08
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:08
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: true
                 } ,  { 
                    id: 35
                    name: Smoked Salmon & Mozzarella
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:37
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:37
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: true
                 } ,  { 
                    id: 36
                    name: Stilton, Spinach and Onion
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:05:05
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:05:05
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: false
             }  ]
         }  ]
 }
```

As you can see I have `orderItem` which contains several `menu_modifier_groups` which then contain several `menu_modifier_items`

What I want to do is transform this data into;

`cartItem` and `cartModifierItems`

`cartItem` will be:

```
id: 159
name: Empanadas (Choice of 2)
description: Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella
price: 700
available: 1
created_at: 2016-01-31 16:50:31
updated_at: 2016-01-31 16:50:31
menu_category_id: 41
restaurant_id: 11
cartModifierItems: // an array containing all menu_modifier_items from all the menu_modifier_groups where selected = true
```

And then `cartModifierItems` will be all `menu_modifier_items` from all the `menu_modifier_groups` where `selected: true` that way I'm left with `cartItem` and `cartItem.cartModifierItems`

Any help or guidance appreciated.

Comment: Do you need a single object that is cartItem that has cartModifierItems property?

Comment: @Klaster_1 yes `cartItem` with an inner `array` called `cartModifierItems` containing all `menu_modifier_items` from all the `menu_modifier_groups` where `selected = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that accepts orderItem and outputs cartItem:

```
function makeCartItem(orderItem) {
    var cartItem = angular.copy(orderItem)
    delete cartItem.menu_modifier_groups
    cartItem.cartModifierItems = orderItem.menu_modifier_groups.reduce(function(acc, menuModifierGroup) {
        const selectedItems = menuModifierGroup.menu_modifier_items.filter(function(item) {
            return item.selected
        })
        return acc.concat(selectedItems)
    }, [])
    return cartItem
}

// {
//  "id": 159,
//  "name": "Empanadas (Choice of 2)",
//  "description": "Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella",
//  "price": 700,
//  "available": 1,
//  "created_at": "2016-01-31 16:50:31",
//  "updated_at": "2016-01-31 16:50:31",
//  "menu_category_id": 41,
//  "restaurant_id": 11,
//  "cartModifierItems": [
//      {
//          "id": 34,
//          "name": "Diced Beef",
//          "price": 0,
//          "created_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:08",
//          "updated_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:08",
//          "menu_modifier_group_id": 9,
//          "restaurant_id": 11,
//          "menu_item_id": 159,
//          "selected": true
//      },
//      {
//          "id": 35,
//          "name": "Smoked Salmon & Mozzarella",
//          "price": 0,
//          "created_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:37",
//          "updated_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:37",
//          "menu_modifier_group_id": 9,
//          "restaurant_id": 11,
//          "menu_item_id": 159,
//          "selected": true
//      }
//  ]
// }
```

Your question isn't really about angular, but more about data transformation in JavaScript. Check out the methods and functions I've used to achieve the result:

1. [angular.copy](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/function/angular.copy). Creates a deep object copy. In conjunction with `delete` I made a new `orderItem`-derived copy without `menu_modifier_groups`:

   ```
   var cartItem = angular.copy(orderItem)
   delete cartItem.menu_modifier_groups
   ```

```
{
    "id": 159,
    "name": "Empanadas (Choice of 2)",
    "description": "Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella",
    "price": 700,
    "available": 1,
    "created_at": "2016-01-31 16:50:31",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-31 16:50:31",
    "menu_category_id": 41,
    "restaurant_id": 11
}
```

2. [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). When called on `menu_modifier_groups`, it accumulates every value into new array (second argument) returned from the function passed as a first argument.
3. [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter). Filters `menu_modifier_items` by a function passed into it. If any traversed item has truish `selected`, then it gets picked.
4. [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Concat). Combines accumulator array with selected items array into a new array that contains both.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wowoyawuko/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: Gracias! Thanks for the guidance and help